# Angular 7 - Calling a function inside of a sibling component after sending an Output() from the sibling

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have three components. A parent component (dashboard.component.ts) which houses two siblings (poll-form.component.ts and poll.component.ts). One of the siblings, poll-component sends an Output() back to the parent called (editEvent)="editPoll($event)". When this Output() is sent I'd like that to trigger a function inside of the other sibling poll-form.component instead of triggering the function in the parent dashboard.component. What's the correct way of doing this?

My current implementation "sort of" works. It fires the function in the parent and then the parent imports the component and calls the function in the sibling component. The issue, however, is that sibling component skips the ngOnInit() and doesn't have access to the component variables needed within the function.

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is break out the form into its own component but the act of opening the form is triggered by a sibling component.

dashboard.component.html

```
<div class="page">
  <div style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-right: 20px; text-align: left;">
    <button type="button" (click)="showCreateModal()" pButton icon="pi pi-check" label="Create Poll"></button>
  </div>
  <div *ngFor="let pollId of pollIds" style="display: inline-block;">
    <app-poll [pollKey]="pollId" (editEvent)="editPoll($event)" (deleteEvent)="deletePoll($event)"></app-poll>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="displayCreateModal">
  <app-poll-form [type]="'create'" (closeEvent)="closeModal($event)"></app-poll-form>
</div>

<div *ngIf="displayEditModal">
  <app-poll-form [type]="'edit'" (closeEvent)="closeModal($event)"></app-poll-form>
</div>
```

poll.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import * as Chart from 'chart.js';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FirebaseService } from '../services/firebase.service';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CardModule } from 'primeng/card';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-poll',
  templateUrl: './poll.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./poll.component.scss']
})
export class PollComponent implements OnInit {
  poll:any;

  @Input()
  pollKey: string;

  @Output()
  editEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();


  constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firebaseService.getPoll(this.pollKey).subscribe(pollDoc => {
      if (!pollDoc.payload.exists) {
        return;
      }
      const pollData:any = pollDoc.payload.data();
      this.poll = {
        id: pollDoc.payload.id,
        helperText: pollData.helperText,
        pollType: pollData.pollType,
        scoringType: pollData.scoringType,
        user: pollData.user
      };
  }

  edit() {
    this.editEvent.emit(this.poll);
  }

}
```

poll-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { DialogModule } from 'primeng/dialog';
import { DropdownModule } from 'primeng/dropdown';
import { AutoCompleteModule } from 'primeng/autocomplete';
import { SelectButtonModule } from 'primeng/selectbutton';

import { FirebaseService } from '../services/firebase.service';

import nflPlayers from '../../assets/data/players-nfl.json';
import nflPollTypes from '../../assets/types/poll-types-nfl.json';
import nflScoringTypes from '../../assets/types/scoring-types-nfl.json';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-poll-form',
  templateUrl: './poll-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./poll-form.component.scss']
})
export class PollFormComponent implements OnInit {
  title:string;
  btnLabel:string;
  selectedScoringType:any;
  choices:any;
  selectedPollType:any;
  selectedPollKey:any;
  displayEditModal:boolean = false;
  displayCreateModal:boolean = false;
  filteredPlayersMultiple: any[];
  displayModal:boolean = true;

  nflPlayers:any = nflPlayers.Players;
  nflPollTypes:any = nflPollTypes.types;
  nflScoringTypes:any = nflScoringTypes.types;
  activePlayers:any;

  @Input()
  type: string;

  @Output()
  closeEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor(
    private firebaseService: FirebaseService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initFormDefaults();
  }

  initFormDefaults() {
    this.choices = [[],[]];
    this.selectedScoringType = this.nflScoringTypes[0];
    this.selectedPollType = this.nflPollTypes[0];

    if (this.type == "create") {
      this.btnLabel = "Create";
      this.title = "Create Poll";
    } else {
      this.btnLabel = "Update";
      this.title = "Edit Poll";
    }

    // Filter out active NFL players
    this.activePlayers = this.nflPlayers.filter(player => player.active == "1");
  }

  editPoll(poll) {
    this.type = "edit"
    this.activePlayers = this.nflPlayers.filter(player => player.active == "1");

    this.selectedPollKey = poll.id;
    // Set scoring type
    this.selectedScoringType = this.nflScoringTypes.find((type) => {
      return type.code == poll.scoringType
    });
    // Set poll type
    this.selectedPollType = this.nflPollTypes.find((type) => {
      return type.code == poll.pollType
    });
    // Populate edit modal with properly formatted Player objects
    for (let i=0; i < poll.choices.length; i++) {
      this.choices[i] = poll.choices[i].players.map((choicePlayer:any) => {
        return this.activePlayers.find(player => player.playerId == choicePlayer.id);
      });
    }
  }

}
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { PollFormComponent } from '../poll-form/poll-form.component';


@Component({
  providers: [PollFormComponent],
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  displayEditModal:boolean = false;

  constructor(

    private pollFormComponent: PollFormComponent
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  editPoll(poll) {
    this.displayEditModal = true;
    this.pollFormComponent.editPoll(poll);
  }

}
```